# What kind of OS or programming language does the aviation use?

Tags: aircraft-systems, avionics, flight-instruments, autopilot

Windows XP because its the most stable system ever ?
C++ because its the most verstatile thing ever ?
Also I am not limiting this question to avionics but to
Garmin GPS/Glass cockpit
B737 Flight systems
Airbus A319 flight systems
F4E Phantom II flight systems
Bell 206 flight systems
In here, Flight systems can mean anything from basic fuel systems to autopilot systems
So which OS/Language does the aviation use ?

Comment: I hope the first line was a joke...

Comment: C++ isn't the most versatile language either.

Comment: So what is a flight system? Like anything modern and more complex than a TV remote or a pressure cooker, you are almost guaranteed to find more than one computers in there. The dash and fly-by-wire would almost certainly run on different computers with different operating systems (but fly-by-wire may also choose not to run any operation system at all) just because the use cases are so different.

Comment: XP IS THE MOST STABLE OS I EVER AND EVER USED and my used OS list 1-W95  2-Xp   3-Vista  4-W7   5-W8.1   6-W10  7-Ubuntu  8-Puppy linux

Comment: It might be the most stable you've used, but none of what you listed are stable enough (or even suitable for) avionics and safety critical systems.

Comment: Windows XP is way too bloated and error prone to use in avionics, even tif the microprocessors used in the equipment are even compatible with x86. Most equipment doesn't even run any sort of Real Time Operating System.

Comment: I Wonder what is the most stable mainstream os is...

Answer (score 0):

For the OS: See [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/31936/24592) answer
btw... XP isn't the most stable system ever.

For the programming language should be any ok as long as it meets the certificate mentioned in the linked answer.